# using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged ,strange exception in Xamarin Android +MVVM Cross

Tags: c#, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am new to Xamarin development.I know following question is a well known problem and discussed in lot of forums.But i couldn't find an exact solution for this problem.So please note that this is not a duplicate question.

I am trying to add a fragment to an android Layout.I am getting the following exception when i inflate the fragment.

```
"using Inflate with a null parent viewGroup is discouraged - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/507"
```

I have checked the given Url which is attached with the exception. Actually there is no an overloaded method for "Binding Inflate" in the assembly which i am using. At this moment i can only access a method which has only two input parameters(Layout,View group) .The issue in Github was closed and noted that this exception is no longer in latest MVVM cross (3.1.1) .But still getting the same exception in the latest stable version.Mvvm Cross 3.1.2 beta has an overloaded method with three parameters where we can pass a Boolean value if the view group is null .But I am getting the same exception even I pass a false for last parameter.What is the wrong i am doing here?Can any one help me out?

Activity

```
[Activity(Label = "HomeView", MainLauncher = true)]
public class HomeView : MvxFragmentActivity
{
//Fragment
private HomeFragment _homeFragment;

    public new HomeViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (HomeViewModel) base.ViewModel; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeView);
        this.AddFragment(_homeFragment);
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        base.OnViewModelSet();
        //Create the Home Fragment
        _homeFragment = new HomeFragment {ViewModel = ViewModel};

    }

    //Add the Fragments to View
    private void AddFragment(MvxFragment fragment)
    {
        var fragmentTrasaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        fragmentTrasaction.Replace(Resource.Id.HomeContainer, _homeFragment);
        fragmentTrasaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class HomeFragment : MvxFragment
{
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
var ignore = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.HomeFragment, null);//Here i am getting the exception
}
}
```

Activity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Test.Droid"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
android:id="@+id/HomeContainer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/Test.Droid"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
android:text="Home"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1" />
```

MVVM packages which I am using

```
"MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"MvvmCross.HotTuna.Droid.Fragging" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"MvvmCross.PortableSupport" version="3.1.1" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
"Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="20.0.0" targetFramework="MonoAndroid42"
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The message you include is just debug trace - not an exception. If there is an exception, please edit the question to include the exception type and the stack trace.

Comment: @Stuart Yes.What you have said is absolutely right.I was looking at debug trace.Actually there was an exception which is not handled at on Create method since oncreate doesn't have the Try Catch block.Actually exception was "Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_height attribute" .I didn't put the  height for Text box which is inside the Fragment.Now it is fixed.Thank you very much .I will update the answer and close this. By the way is Can you suggest me a  best practice for Exception handling or logging in Xamarin Cross platform projects ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking at debug trace.Actually there was an exception which is not handled at on Create method since oncreate doesn't have the Try Catch block.Actually exception was "Binary XML file line #1: You must supply a layout_height attribute" .I didn't put the height for Text box which is inside the Fragment.Now it is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have found the issue, here but you should still not pass a null parent into the inflator. If you do then any theme settings etc you put on the parents are not going to effect the view you inflate. Instead pass false as a third argument so that the view doesn't get attached to the parent, but does get the options from it.

Comment: Thank you.Yes it is true?But 3.1.1 Stable version doesn't have the third argument.Shall i switch to 3.1.2 beta version?.is that stable enough for big projects?